# How to get all options for all store views for a single attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, custom-options, store-view

I am trying to retrieve all options for all store views for a single attribute e.g. `color`.

For the attribute `color` I have created two options `blue` and `white`. I have tried the following code that is suppose to return all the options labels for all store views, but only returns the `admin` option label for me.

```
$option_arr = array();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option) {
  $option_arr[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
// $option_arr contains Array([4] => Blue, [3] => White)
```

The following works fine for getting all the attribute `color` titles for each store view, but does not work for options.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load();
$attribute_title = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
// $attribute_title contains Array([1] => ~~~, [2] =>Color, [3] => Couleur, [4] => Còôlòôr)
```

[image: Screenshot of my color attribute and options.]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
    /**
     * @var $config  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     * @var $options Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection
     */
    $storeId   = 3;
    $config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
    $attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');
    $values    = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    print_r($values);

    //here is another method
    $options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
    $values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter($storeId)->toOptionArray();
    print_r($values);
```

Comment: And how to save it to 1 certain storeview?