# How to get list of attribute options in frontend view?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-options

I'm writing a custom display for certain attributes based on its label. Within the 'configurable.phtml' file, it has the following lines:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
```

I can loop through the attributes array and check the label no problem:

```
$special_attr = false;
foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute) {
    echo $_attribute->getLabel().'<br>';
    if ($_attribute->getLabel() === 'FooBar') {
        $special_attr = $_attribute;
    }
}
```

This will print out all of the labels ("Color", "Size", etc.). I'm trying to get a list of all options and their values given this special attribute now, and I'm completely stumped. All of the other questions I have found have said something along the lines of using `->getSource()->getAllOptions(false)`, however, calling `getSource()` on this attribute just returns null.

How can I get all options given this special attribute?

```
if ($special_attr) {
    $options = $special_attr->??????
    // list all options??
}
```

Comment: are you sure the special attribute in your question is a select attribute ?

Comment: use full links : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5092/how-to-get-all-options-for-all-store-views-for-a-single-attribute 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994224/get-a-list-of-attribute-options-from-magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to get options of configurable attributes within `configurable.phtml`

```
$special_attr = false;
foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute) {
    echo $_attribute->getLabel().'<br>';
    if ($_attribute->getLabel() === 'FooBar') {
        $special_attr = $_attribute->getPrices();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the trick lies in `$_attribute->getPrices()`. This will give you an output like this for `color` attribute (if that is configurable)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_super_attribute_id] => 13
        [value_index] => 183
        [label] => Brown
        [default_label] => Brown
        [store_label] => Brown
        [is_percent] => 0
        [pricing_value] => 10.0000
        [use_default_value] => 1
        [value_id] => 15
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_super_attribute_id] => 13
        [value_index] => 174
        [label] => Orange
        [default_label] => Orange
        [store_label] => Orange
        [is_percent] => 0
        [pricing_value] => 20.0000
        [use_default_value] => 1
        [value_id] => 16
    )

)
```

I believe this will be enough in your case.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. I wish this info was under something less misleading than "getPrices" though. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenJeffries In fact, yes it is a misleading terminology. But on another hand, it is logical too. Because each option of a configurable product determine the actual price of configurable product